# How to reverse distance scale in ggdendrogram and to add label under the distance scale?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, ggdendro

I am using ggdendrogram to construct a dendrogram based on Jaccard matrix. Is there a way to reverse the distance scale from 0 - 1 to 1 - 0 and to add text under the distance scale with ggdendrogram? Cheers.

Comment: To reverse you can `abs(DATA - 1)`

Comment: I did try it, but it doesn't work

Comment: I am a bit late for the party, but maybe you can try something like `+ scale_y_reverse(breaks=seq(0,1,0.25))` for reversing the axis? And a simple `+ ylab("banana")` for the text?